# How to limit pandas interpolation when there is more NaN than the limit

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I would like to interpolate a pandas dataframe but I could not find a simple solution to my issue.
Here is my pandas df:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array([numpy.nan, 1, 1, numpy.nan, \
    numpy.nan, 1, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, numpy.nan, 1]),columns=['a'])

      a
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   1.0
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  1.0
```

I want the following result:

```
      a
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   1.0
5   1.0
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  1.0
```

To do that, I use the interpolate function but it always extrapolate the data:

```
df2=df.interpolate(limit=2, limit_area='inside' ,method='linear')
      a
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   1.0
5   1.0
6   1.0
7   1.0
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  1.0
```

Is it possible to interpolate ONLY if there is a non NaN value in the range of the limit parameter? (ie: The value for line 6 and 7 should be NaN because line 8 is also a NaN). I have the impression that limit_area is only for the end of the df.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve what you want first create a Series that counts the number of consecutive `NaN` values for each group of `NaN` and broadcasts that value back to each row in the group. Then interpolate the entire Series and use `mask` to `NaN` everything that shouldn't have been interpolated.

```
s = df['a'].notnull()
s = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()

m = df.groupby([s, df['a'].isnull()])['a'].transform('size').where(df['a'].isnull())
#0     1.0
#1     NaN
#2     NaN
#3     2.0
#4     2.0
#5     NaN
#6     4.0
#7     4.0
#8     4.0
#9     4.0
#10    NaN

df.interpolate(limit_area='inside', method='linear').mask(m>2)
```

---

```
      a
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   1.0
5   1.0
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  1.0
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what i want!